# Is there a workaround when hitting the maximum summands in =sum in an Excel formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I am hitting a limit when I try to assign a sum to a cells formula:

```
cells(y,x).formula = "=sum(G65,H74,I38,J20,G22, .... ,K19,L22)"
```

It seems as though I can't have more than 30 summands in a **=sum** formula.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: This is using the VBA programming language built into excel.  As much as one might like to deny it, this is still a programming question...

Comment: @Adam Davis.  I would not call this programming.  Writing VBA to automate Excel is definitely programming.  Putting a formula into a cell is not programming.

Comment: The code `cells(y,x).formula = "=sum(G65,H74,I38,J20,G22, .... ,K19,L22)"` is VBA code to write into a cell.  You cannot put that line into an cell and expect any response - you have to load it into the VBA editor/interpretor for it to have any effect.

Comment: @Sam: Last time I checked there was an Excel-Formula tag here on stackoverflow. Spreadsheet formulas are integral parts of the application design (spreadsheet design if you will). So whether in code, or in the interface they are programming. Yeah, I said that. Excel formulas are programming. Very valid question here. Syntax, language, best practice: all valid subjects for a CODE question.

Comment: @guitarthrower, The fact that there's a tag here means nothing.  Anyone with a 250 rep can create whatever tag they want.  According to this question on meta, questions on Excel formulas belong on superuser.com.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for the link. It seems that most of the answers there seem to agree with me though. Although, I concede that not all formula questions need to be here, they don't necessarily always need to moved to SU.

Answer (score 4):

Use pluses instead.

Answer (score 4):

Options:

- A1 + A2 + ... + An
- Sum(A1,A2) + ... + Sum(An, Am)
- Sum(A1,A2,Sum(An,Am))

The theird option doesn't use an plus-signs, in case you're alergic.

Comment: `+` allergies are nothing to be sneezed at.

Answer (score 2):

You could group the cells by defining names for them or split the sum-formula into 
`=sum(...) + sum(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can cascade the sums as well:

```
cells(y,x).formula = "=sum(sum(G65,H74,...,I38,J20), sum(G22, .... ,K19,L22))"
```

Keep in mind that the formula length limit for Excel is 1,024 characters, so you might run into that limit if your formula needs to be much longer.  If so, use other cells to act as intermediate formulas and sum them.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's pretty easy to get around this. Just select the cells you want in advance (if they are non-ajoining, just hold down the Ctrl key as you are selecting them). Once you have all selected, just give them a name. So for example:

Cell:

- A3 = 3
- G22 = 4
- D1 = 5

Select them by holding down the Ctrl key and selecting each individually. Then, in the box to the left of the formula bar, type a name for them, like "MyCells" and hit enter. In your code, now use `Cells(y,x).formula = "=sum(MyCells)"`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to be used just for summing. It would contain a formula that pulls each row's number into the new column and then your sum formula for the code would look like this:

```
cells(y,x).formula = "=sum(Q1:Q100)"
```

Where Q1:Q100 would be the new column with the numbers to be summed.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show it, but if all of your cells are in the same row or column and you're selecting individual sums to avoid intermediate calculations, consider using SUBTOTAL.  See http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2008/01/04/subtotals-ignoring-subtotals/

Answer (score 0):

One method of getting around the String Length issue is breaking down the formula into 'chunks' and replacing those chunks after setting the formula.

Let's say you have some range, named '`r`', and you have an if condition whose parameters are each 120 bytes long:

```
r.Formula = "=IF(P_01, P_02, P_03)"
r.Replace "P_01", "Parameter 1"
r.Replace "P_02", "Parameter 2"
r.Replace "P_03", "Parameter 3"
```

Things get a bit tricky when you have very long formulas, you have to break it down in successive steps, each with their own sub-expressions.

The caveat: you cannot introduce a syntax error at any point or it shall fail.  I've encountered this sufficiently enough to have code like so:

```
m_rng_CurrentListItem.Replace "C_2_", m_str_FormulaReplacement1
m_rng_CurrentListItem.Replace "C_3_", m_str_FormulaReplacement2
m_rng_CurrentListItem.Replace "C_4_", m_str_FormulaReplacement3
m_rng_CurrentListItem.Replace "C_5_", m_str_FormulaReplacement4
m_rng_CurrentListItem.Replace "R_2_", m_str_FormulaReplacement5
m_rng_CurrentListItem.Replace "C_6_", m_str_FormulaReplacement6
```

Microsoft really should fix this limitation because it's a report automation headache.

*Edit*
I decided to do a little example with this and expanded it into a few classes that can be used to represent a broader solution.

You can download it [here](http://www.abstraction-project.com/documents/excel/FunctionCalls.xlsm).  To best illustrate this, open the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11), put it to the right of your screen, excel to the left of the screen.  In the worksheet select cell A1, in VBA, Go to Line 291 of the 'FormulaGeneration' module.  Place a break point there.  On Line 317 is a method named 'test', run that method and watch as the formula gradually progresses.  Below I've placed the steps it should follow, the numbers may change.

1

```
{=F_C_35}
```

2

```
{=SUM(F_C_34)}
```

3

```
{=SUM(IF(B_O_29, L_C_33, B_O_32))}
```

4

```
{=SUM(IF(P_E_27 = P_E_28, L_C_33, B_O_32))}
```

. . . Truncated

34

```
{=SUM(IF(((TestTable3[Right Column] > 5)&(TestTable3[Right Column] < 50)&(TestTable3[Left Column] <> "Exclude Marker")&(TestTable3[Left Column] <> "Exclude Marker 19")) = (TRUE&TRUE&TRUE&TRUE), TestTable3[Right Column], L_C_30 + I_V_31))}
```

35

```
{=SUM(IF(((TestTable3[Right Column] > 5)&(TestTable3[Right Column] < 50)&(TestTable3[Left Column] <> "Exclude Marker")&(TestTable3[Left Column] <> "Exclude Marker 19")) = (TRUE&TRUE&TRUE&TRUE), TestTable3[Right Column], TestTable3[Right Column] + I_V_31))}
```

36

```
{=SUM(IF(((TestTable3[Right Column] > 5)&(TestTable3[Right Column] < 50)&(TestTable3[Left Column] <> "Exclude Marker")&(TestTable3[Left Column] <> "Exclude Marker 19")) = (TRUE&TRUE&TRUE&TRUE), TestTable3[Right Column], TestTable3[Right Column] + 100))}
```

After expanding it some to my needs (not reflected in example, and dropping the 'xl' prefix in favor of 'fg'), I've used it to create 700+ character expressions; fgRangedIndex is like so: INDEX(vArray, vRow1, [vColumn1]):Index(vArray, vRow2, [vColumn2]).

```
Set m_exp_CurrentExpression = _
    fgIfCall( _
        fgAndCall(fgBinaryOperation(m_nam_PreviousSelection, fgBinOpInequality, "None", True), _
            fgBinaryOperation(m_nam_PreviousSelection, fgBinOpInequality, vbNullString, True)), _
        fgIndexCall( _
            fgRangedIndex(m_nam_PreviousList, 2, fgCountACall(m_nam_PreviousList), 1, 1), _
            fgMatchCall(0, _
                fgIfCall( _
                    fgComplexAndCondition( _
                        fgBinaryOperation( _
                            fgRangedIndex(m_nam_PreviousList, 2, fgCountACall(m_nam_PreviousList), 1, 1), fgBinOpInequality, m_nam_PreviousSelection), _
                        fgBinaryOperation(fgRowCall(fgRangedIndex(m_nam_PreviousList, 2, fgCountACall(m_nam_PreviousList), 1, 1)), fgBinOpGreaterThanOrEqualTo, fgRowCall()), _
                        fgIsNaCall(fgMatchCall(fgRangedIndex(m_nam_PreviousList, 2, fgCountACall(m_nam_PreviousList), 1, 1), _
                                               fgRangedIndex(m_nam_CurrentName, 1, fgBinaryOperation(fgRowCall(), fgBinOpSubtraction, fgRowCall(fgIndexCall(m_nam_PreviousList, 1, 1)), True), 1, 1), 0))), 0, 1), 0), 1), vbNullString)
```

Which Yields:

```
{=IF(AND((AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_SELECTION_1 <> "None"), (AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_SELECTION_1 <> "")), INDEX((INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, 2, 1):INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, COUNTA(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1), 1)), MATCH(0, IF(((((INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, 2, 1):INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, COUNTA(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1), 1)) <> AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_SELECTION_1))&((ROW((INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, 2, 1):INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, COUNTA(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1), 1))) >= ROW()))&(ISNA(MATCH((INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, 2, 1):INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, COUNTA(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1), 1)), (INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_2, 1, 1):INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_2, (ROW() - ROW(INDEX(AMBIGUATED_NAME_CRITERION_1, 1, 1))), 1)), 0)))) = (TRUE&TRUE&TRUE), 0, 1), 0), 1), "")}
```